# proving $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^{n-1}\left\{(n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right\}}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}dx = \frac{b^{n-1}-a^{n-1}}{2(a+b)}$

Tags: calculus

How can we prove $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^{n-1}\left\{(n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right\}}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}dx = \frac{b^{n-1}-a^{n-1}}{2(a+b)}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using Hit and Trail ,We get

$\displaystyle \frac{x^{n-1}\left\{(n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right\}}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}=\frac{x^n}{(x+a)(x+b)}$

But I did not Understand How can I get it.

Help me

Thanks

Comment: May be, just differentiate the rhs of your last equation and xheck that you get the lhs ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d\left[\dfrac{x^n}{(x+a)(x+b)}\right]}{dx}=\frac1{(x+a)(x+b)}nx^{n-1}-x^n\frac{2ax+(a+b)}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}$$

$$=x^{n-1}\frac{n(x+a)(x+b)-2ax^2-(a+b)x}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}$$

$$=\frac{x^{n-1}\left\{(n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right\}}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}$$

$$\implies\int\left[\frac{x^{n-1}\left\{(n-2)x^2+(n-1)(a+b)x+nab\right\}}{(x+a)^2(x+b)^2}\right]dx$$

$$=\int\frac{d\left[\dfrac{x^n}{(x+a)(x+b)}\right]}{dx}dx=\dfrac{x^n}{(x+a)(x+b)}+K$$

Comment: I suppose typo's at the very beginning of your answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks

Comment: I enjoy when I am able to notice small typo's as this one ! Being almost blind, at least my brain seems to still work a little !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Sorry to hear first part, but happy to know the last. Keep your good job

Comment: Don't be sorry at all, please ! What is interesting is that (quoting you), now "you know the last". So, this was not obvious to you up to now !!! Be sure I am joking and kidding you ! Cheers